# Why is a query with one outer join taking so long?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.TOUR, t.ROUND, t.ID1, t.ID2
FROM belgarath.today_atp AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN belgarath.match_ as m
ON m.tour_id = 0
AND t.TOUR = m.tours_ID_T
AND t.ROUND = m.rounds_ID_R
AND t.ID1 = m.today_players_ID1
AND t.ID2 = m.today_players_ID2
WHERE m.id_ IS NULL;
```

I'm looking to get the records from `today_atp` where they don't exist in `match_`.

I've given up on the query after 30 mins as this seems like it's taking too long for tables which have 700 rows (`today_atp`) and 1.4m rows (`match_`).

I tried just pulling one record via this query:

```
SELECT t.TOUR, t.ROUND, t.ID1, t.ID2
FROM belgarath.today_atp AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN belgarath.match_ as m
ON m.tour_id = 0
AND t.TOUR = m.tours_ID_T
AND t.ROUND = m.rounds_ID_R
AND t.ID1 = m.today_players_ID1
AND t.ID2 = m.today_players_ID2
WHERE m.id_ IS NULL
AND t.TOUR = 16756
AND t.ROUND = 2
AND t.ID1 = 29591
AND t.ID2 = 37741;
```

This takes 30 seconds.

The specs for the two tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `match_` (
  `id_` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time_scheduled` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time_actual` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tour_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tournament_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `tours_ID_T` int NOT NULL,
  `rounds_ID_R` int NOT NULL,
  `today_players_ID1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `today_players_ID2` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `games_players_ID1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `games_players_ID2` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `uncertainty_bin` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_pred_ogion` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_pred_rf_ogion` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_pred_ged` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_pred_rf_ged` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `winning_player` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_sets` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `result_type_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_pinnacle_closing_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_pinnacle_closing_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_pinnacle_opening_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_pinnacle_opening_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_match_data_retrieved` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__tours_ID_T` (`tours_ID_T`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__today_players_ID1` (`today_players_ID1`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__games_players_ID1` (`games_players_ID1`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__tour_id` (`tour_id`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__rounds_ID_R` (`rounds_ID_R`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__today_players_ID2` (`today_players_ID2`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__games_players_ID2` (`games_players_ID2`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__uncertainty_bin` (`uncertainty_bin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE `today_atp` (
  `TOUR` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DATE_GAME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID1` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ID2` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ROUND` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DRAW` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RESULT` tinytext,
  `COMPLETE` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `live` char(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_GAME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `RESERVE_INT` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `RESERVE_CHAR` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `today_atp_TOUR` (`TOUR`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `today_atp_ROUND` (`ROUND`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `today_atp_ID1` (`ID1`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `today_atp_ID2` (`ID2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Is there anything obvious that jumps out as to why it would be taking so long?

I have seen from other posts that `CHARSET` can be a problem but changing `today_atp` to `utf8mb4` doesn't make a difference (I'm not sure how to set the `COLLATE` part via workbench).

(P.S. Some normalisation of the tables is definitely on my to do list!)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think that with such a query, for each row in the `today_atp` table, the DBMS scans the entire `match_` table just to check for no occurrences from `today_atp`

Comment: This is a choice when WHERE NOT EXISTS is more fast. Especially when proper index exists.

Comment: @Akina - thanks for replying. Are you saying that this query should take over 30 mins? I figured 700 searches of a 1.4m row table shouldn't take that long surely?

Comment: Not 700 searches but 700*1.4m comparings. Your tables have no suitable indexes for this query. If you'd use WHERE NOT EXISTS - you'll have 700 searches (fullscans I think - because of the index absence again). PS. `match_` indexing is strange... it seems that indexes were created just to have them.

Comment: @Akina - I've just realised there's no primary key (doh!) set on ```match_``` - would this make a difference? How would you suggest setting up the indexes to make this query faster?